# Select only top 10 values from a JSON file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, sorting

I have a JSON file that I load and display with jQuery. But I just want to get the top 10 with the highest value.

So for example.

**JSON:**

```
{
"value": {
    "number": "12",
    "number": "11",
    "number": "10",
    "number": "9",
    "number": "8",
    "number": "7",
    "number": "6",
    "number": "5",
    "number": "4",
    "number": "3",
    "number": "2",
    "number": "1",
    "number": "0",
  }
}
```

I only want to get the highest 10, so that would be 12 to 3 in this example. Please note all values strings format, not numbers.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: This is not valid JSON: `{ "value": { "number": "12", "number": "11" ... } }` JSON only support one property with each name. You can use Arrays to store set of data. `{"numbers": [1,2,3,4,5]}`

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid JSON: `{ "value": { "number": "12", "number": "11" ... } }`

JSON only support one property with each name. You can use Arrays to store set of data:

```
{"numbers": [1,2,3,4,5]}
```

If you store the data as an Array you can use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var data= {"numbers": [1,2,3,4,5]};

data.numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
});

var to2 = data.numbers.slice(0, 2); // [5,4]
```

Note that `.sort` work on the input array while `.slice` returns a new array.

Comment: +1, but technically the only invalid thing about the quoted JSON is the trailing comma after `"0"`. Repeating the same member name is a "SHOULD NOT" in the spec (and of course, pointless), but not a "MUST NOT": http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt The resulting object, of course, only has one member with that name. In a *JavaScript* object initializer in loose mode, the resulting member would have the value of the last one listed, but the JSON spec seems to be silent on that point. (In JS strict mode, it's a nice useful syntax error.)

Comment: Yes i know it isn't valid json, I just typed it quickly so I could explain the problem. Will try your solution!